# PHP Array to HTML hierarchy (multiple breadcrumb trails)

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, breadcrumbs

I have a array in php that looks like this when doing a print_r($breadcrumb)

```
Array (
    [url] => /category/
    [text] => Category
)
Array (
    [url] => /category/subcategory/
    [text] => Subcategory
)
Array (
    [url] => /category/subcategory/subsubcategory/
    [text] => Subsubcategory
)
```

I want this breadcrumb to display as

```
Category > Subcategory > Subsubcategory
```

According to [Google docs](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185417), the HTML should look like this:

```
<div xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#"> 
  <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
    <a href="/category/" rel="v:url" property="v:title">
      Category
    </a> ›
    <span rel="v:child">
      <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
        <a href="/category/subcategory/" rel="v:url" property="v:title">
          Subcategory
        </a> ›
        <span rel="v:child">         
          <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
            <a href="/category/subcategory/subsubcategory/" rel="v:url" property="v:title">
              Subsubcategory
            </a> ›          
          </span>
        </span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

How can I go from PHP array to HTML?

I've looked at [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997548/php-formatting-multi-dimensional-array-as-html), but they don't work in my scenario

Comment: Sounds like you're after [PHP's DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). Also you're going to have a much easier time if your initial array is structured in the same way you intend for the output. Right now, you're going to have to count to number of occurrences of "sub" within `text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would go about this:

The PHP:

```
<?php
    $breadcrumb = array(
        array(
            'url' => '/category/',
            'text' => 'Category'
        ),
        array(
            'url' => '/category/subcategory/',
            'text' => 'Subcategory'
        ),
        array(
            'url' => '/category/subcategory/subcategory',
            'text' => 'Subsubcategory'
        )
    );
    $children = count($breadcrumb) - 1;
?>
```

The display markup:

```
<div xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#">
    <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($breadcrumb); $i++) : ?>
        <?php if ($i == 0) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb[0]['url']; ?>" rel="v:url" property="v:title"><?php echo $breadcrumb[0]['text']; ?></a> › 
        <?php else : ?>
        <span rel="v:child">
            <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
                <a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb[$i]['url']; ?>" rel="v:url" property="v:title"><?php echo $breadcrumb[$i]['text']; ?></a> ›
        <?php endif; ?> 
        <?php endfor; ?>
        <?php echo str_repeat("</span>\r\n</span>\r\n", $children); ?>
    </span>
</div>
```

This approach will also allow deeper sub categories if necessary.

Hope it helps

Updated display code:

```
<div xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#">
    <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($breadcrumb); $i++) : ?>
        <?php if ($i == 0) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb[0]['url']; ?>" rel="v:url" property="v:title"><?php echo $breadcrumb[0]['text']; ?></a> › 
        <?php else : ?>
        <span rel="v:child">
            <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
                <a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb[$i]['url']; ?>" rel="v:url" property="v:title"><?php echo $breadcrumb[$i]['text']; ?></a><?php if ($i < $children):?> › <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?> 
        <?php endfor; ?>
        <?php echo str_repeat("</span>\r\n</span>\r\n", $children); ?>
    </span>
</div>
```

The above code trims the last > symbol from the end :)

Comment: I thought that there was need for a recursive function, but your answer is actually working. Not a surprise for you, but for me :) THANK YOU!!